# How to get Windows 7 to try to install a device driver again?

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, logitech-mouse

I have a wireless Logitech mouse with a USB receiver. I am trying to connect it to a Dell laptop with Windows7 64bit. The first time I put it in a USB port, Windows 7 tries to detect it and install a driver but I get a "Device driver was not successfully installed". It does this when I try other USB ports. Device manager doesn't show anything new being installed.

However I can't get Windows 7 to try again if I reinsert the USB receiver. It seems Win7 either installed something or has a flag that the device doesn't work properly.

I need to have Win7 in clear state as if I am putting the USB device in for the first time. How do I do this so that every time I insert the USB device, Win7 tries to install the device driver. (I don't care if it doesn't install the driver successfully at the time). I am trying to find out why it's failing and I need the details info.

(I installed SetPoint, the mouse software, and the laptop still can't detect the mouse)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Device Manager, click on the `View` menu and then `Show hidden devices`. Delete the broken ones. Refresh the window or restart Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do that by going to `Control Panel` > `System` > `Device Manager`

When the device window opens, `right click` on problematic driver and choose `Uninstall` option.

Once the process is finished right click on any driver and choose `Scan for hardware changes` option.

Also you should check out for the latest available software for your Windows version on [Logitech Support](https://support.logitech.com/en_us/downloads) website. Download and install it and then restart computer.